# PHP build tutorial assumes libphp5.so was built - it wasn't

Tags: linux, fedora, php, apache-http-server, make

I'm following this tutorial http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.unix.apache2.php

I've gotten to the part where `libphp5.so` should magically be in `modules/` after the PHP install, but it's not. I've run

```
find / -name libphp5.so -print
```

With no results. I've also backtracked the tutorial and checked if there is any mention of libphp5.so before this point - there is not.

if there a `./configure` option that decides if the module gets built?

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

```
--with-apxs=/path/to/apxs
```

or

```
--with-apxs2=/path/to/apxs
```

depending if you have Apache 1.x or Apache 2.x installed.

apxs is the Apache module auto-configuration system.  It comes with Apache, so obviously Apache should be installed first.  You can find out where apxs is installed with:

```
$ which apxs
/usr/local/sbin/apxs
```

So, if you have Apache 2.x installed, and you find apxs is in /usr/local/sbin it would be:

```
configure --with-apxs2=/usr/local/sbin/apxs ... other args ...
```

You could of course combine the two steps with:

```
configure --with-apxs2=`which apxs`... other args ...
```